# Best way to custom sort a flex array?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, sorting

Here are the strings this array can contain (in the correct order):

'recipients,' 'columnSelector,' 'headerImageLink,' 'title,' 'mainText,' 'text,' 'bodyImage'

Now, to sort them, I obviously don't want to do something like this:

```
if( a == 'columnSelector' && b == 'headerImageLink' ) return -1;
else if( a == 'columnSelector' && b == 'title' ) return -1;
else if( a == 'columnSelector' && b == 'mainText' ) return -1;
```

So that brings up an interesting thing. I know you can optimize the above some using something like this:

```
if( a == 'columnSelector' || a == 'bodyImage' ) return -1;
```

This would get the last two, but lately I have just wanted community input on issues I have had in the past. So the question is, what is the best way to write a custom sort, using a relatively random order (not alphabetical, etc)?

Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking you could do something like this: var correctOrder:Array = [all,strings,in,here]; if( correctOrder.indexOf(a) < correctOrder.indexOf(b) ) return -1; etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use [Array.sort](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort%28%29) with a compareFunction that defines your custom algorithm?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm asking for logic inside of the compareFunction (which the return -1, return 1, etc should tell you)

Comment: @andrewpthorp That was not obvious to me from the original question.  Since the sorting is arbitrary; I'd turn your string into objects and add an "ordering" numerical field to it.   Conceptually this is like a Netflix queue; there is no way Netflix and determine what you want to watch next.  It is up to us to manage our queue.  I've used the same approach to determine the order that products should be displayed on the Flextras home page as another example.

Comment: You think I should have another data type that has a value and a weight?

Comment: @andrewpthorp It is one approach which I have faith will work.  I'm rarely dealing with arrays of simple values though; so adding another poperty to the object is no big deal.  Moving from a string to an object is slightly more work. :-)

Comment: Right, I could go about it that way, but what would the logic look like for something like that? (Edit your answer with logic so I can give it the green check)